# Android - Como exportar o banco de dados em um arquivo csv?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, csv

Tenho um aplicativo que coleta e armazena informação num banco de dados, e o usuário pode consultar esses dados dentro do próprio aplicativo.
Porém, gostaria de inserir um botão para exportar o banco de dados em um arquivo `.csv`.

Alguém já fez ou já viu e testou um exemplo onde realmente funciona? Achei diversas tentativas no *StaCkOverFlow* gringo, assim como em alguns sites de fora, mas nenhum que funcionasse.

Estou usando o Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Abaixo a solução que implementei.

1- Inclua no projeto o opencsv.jar

2-

```
 private boolean criaCsv(String select, long parametro, String nomeArquivoCsv) throws Exception
        {
            try{                
                File arquivoCsv =  new File( caminho + nomeArquivoCsv );
                arquivoCsv.createNewFile();
                CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(arquivoCsv), CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR);
                Boolean includeHeaders = false;

                PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(select, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                ps.setFetchSize(FETCH_BD);
                ps.setLong(1, parametro);

                ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) ps.executeQuery();
                writer.writeAll(resultSet, includeHeaders);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                log.error("",e);
                return false;
            }
        }


public Connection getConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            if( conn == null || conn.isClosed()){

                conn = dataSource.getConnection();
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            log.error("", e);
        }

        return conn;
    }
```

Comment: O banco está no dispositivo Android, pode explicar como é feita a *connection* ao banco?

Comment: Abaixo como criar conexão com o banco no Android.

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private Context context;
public static final String CRIA_TABELA_DIARIO = "create table if not exists NOMETABELA( DATA integer primary key autoincrement,  DESC string )";       
public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance(){
  if(database == null)
  {
   database = context.openOrCreateDatabase(nomeBanco, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
   database.execSQL(ConstantesBanco.CRIA_TABELA_DIARIO);
  }
  return database;
 }

Comment: Edite a resposta e coloque lá esse código. No entanto o que eu queria saber é que método é aquele `getConnection()`.

Comment: Qualquer nova informação que melhore a resposta deve ser colocada nela(editando-a) em vez de colocá-la num comentário.

Comment: É um código para aplicação que não é Android.
public Connection getConnection()
 {
  try
  {
   if( conn == null || conn.isClosed()){

    conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
   }
  } catch (SQLException e)
  {
   log.error("", e);
  }

  return conn;
 }

Answer (score -2):

Dê uma olhada nesse link:
https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

> CSV Export
>
> To export an SQLite table (or part of a table) as CSV, simply set the
>   "mode" to "csv" and then run a query to extract the desired rows of
>   the table.
>
> **> sqlite> .header on 
>   sqlite> .mode csv 
>   sqlite> .once c:/work/dataout.csv
>   sqlite> SELECT * FROM tab1; 
>   sqlite> .system c:/work/dataout.csv**
>
> In the example above, the ".header on" line causes column labels to be
>   printed as the first row of output. This means that the first row of
>   the resulting CSV file will contain column labels. If column labels
>   are not desired, set ".header off" instead. (The ".header off" setting
>   is the default and can be omitted if the headers have not been
>   previously turned on.)
>
> The line ".once FILENAME" causes all query output to go into the named
>   file instead of being printed on the console. In the example above,
>   that line causes the CSV content to be written into a file named
>   "C:/work/dataout.csv".
>
> The final line of the example (the ".system c:/work/dataout.csv") has
>   the same effect as double-clicking on the c:/work/dataout.csv file in
>   windows. This will typically bring up a spreadsheet program to display
>   the CSV file. That command only works as shown on Windows. The
>   equivalent line on a Mac would be ".system open /work/dataout.csv". On
>   Linux and other unix systems you will need to enter something like
>   ".system libreoffice /work/dataout.csv", substituting your preferred
>   CSV viewing program for "libreoffice".

Espero ter ajudado!
Boa sorte!

Comment: Gustavo, a tua resposta está basicamente em Inglês... dá para [edit] e traduzir pelo menos partes? Obrigado!